# Javascript: Reduce cyclomatic complexity

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, cyclomatic-complexity

```js
function(response) {
  if (response.bMap && SelType === 'q') {
    setDefaultQQ(response.bMap);
  } else if (response.bMap && SelType === 'a') {
    setDefaultAA(response.bMap);
  } else if (response.bMap && SelType === 'o') {
    setDefaultOO(response.bMap);
  } else if (response.mMap && SelType === 'm') {
    setDefaultMM(response.mMap);
  } else if (response.bMap && SelType === 'p') {
    setDefaultPP(response.bMap);
  } else if (response.eMap && SelType === 'e') {
    setDefaultEE(response.eMap);
  } else {
    setDefaultData();
    showModal();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to reduce this conditional statement into shorter form and better readability

Comment: Not exactly related, but this questions seems to conflict with your profile just a bit ; ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use an object to map the SelType specific  methods

```
var methods = {
  'a': setDefaultQQ,
  'o': setDefaultOO,
  'm': setDefaultMM,
  ....    
}

if(response.bMap && methods[SelType]){
   methods[SelType](response.bMap);
}else{
   setDefaultData();
   showModal();
}
```

Comment: you are missing my other keys eMap and Mmap

Comment: so you will need additional logic. My guess is you could have used one method and pass in response object as argument and do everything there

Comment: Yes I was adding additional logic, but this is the method, where i am passing my response param, Do you mean to add me another method to seperate the logic ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a good way but how about this

`eval("setDefault"+SelType.toUpperCase()+SelType.toUpperCase()+"(response."+SelType.toUpperCase()+"Map);");`

But certainly not the best way.

Comment: It's interesting to see that this could be done this way but please don't use `eval()` unless you really have to (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!). You own code and @charlietfl's answer proves that it is not necessary :)

Comment: I wanted to make it dynamic. If someday you add another `SelType`, you won't have to come back and update `SelType` key to function mapping etc.

Comment: kawadhiya21 that makes sense, but still i am not allowed to use eval here..